# ¿Cómo acceder a objetos JSON en C# como en PHP?

Tags: c#, json

Estoy realizando un `WebService` entre `PHP` y `C#` y estoy intercambiando objetos `JSON` entre ellos. Pero me atoré un poco en la manera en la que `C#` manipula `JSON`.

Lo que busco lograr es poder acceder a los `objetos` como lo hace `PHP` como aquí:

El **JSON** al que quiero acceder, el cual tiene 2 objetos dentro, uno llamado `empleados` el cual contiene un `array asociativo` y el otro `titulo` que solo contiene un `string`:

```
    {
     "empleados": [
         {
           "nombre": "Man",
           "apellidos": "torres"
         }
       ],

     "titulo": "soy titulo"
    }
```

Código `PHP`:

Aquí solamente se decodifica el `JSON` y se manipulan los objetos que estén dentro de él con el operador `->`

```
    $d = json_decode($json);//decodifico el json
    
    foreach ($d->empleados as $key) { //accedo al objeto empleados y solo imprimo los nombres
        
        echo $key->nombre;
    }

    echo $d->titulo; // solo imprimo el string del objeto titulo
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero el problema viene cuando quiero enviar el mismo `JSON` a `C#`, cabe mencionar que utilizo la librería `newtonsoft` para manipular los objetos `JSON`. Pero para poder acceder a los objetos, se tiene que crear una `clase` con los atributos a lo cuales se quiere acceder, y hasta ahí todo bien, puedo acceder al objeto **empleados** pero no puedo acceder al objeto **titulo**.

Quisiera saber si de alguna manera se puede acceder a ese objeto sin la necesidad de crear otra `clase`

Esta es la `clase`:

```
public class Datos
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellidos { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
}
```

Código `C#` para acceder a `JSON`:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(response.Content);//recibe el JSON
JArray a = (JArray)o["empleados"];//Le indico el objeto a recorrer, en este caso empleados
IList<Datos> person = a.ToObject<IList<Datos>>();//lo convierte en lista

foreach (var i in person)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.Nombre); //Lo recorro y se imprimen solo los objetos nombre
}
```

Mi pregunta aquí es, ¿Cómo ingreso al valor del objeto `titulo`?... Solamente haciendo una decodificación como en `PHP` o una forma más rápida/óptima sin escribir tanto código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez tengas el `Parse` a un `JObject` puedes acceder a las propiedades utilizando los indizadores.

Por ejemplo:

```csharp
JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(response.Content);

foreach (var item in jsonObj["empleados"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["nombre"]);
}

Console.WriteLine(jsonObj["titulo"]);
```

También se puede utilizar el método `GetValue` por ejemplo: `jsonObj.GetValue("titulo")`.

Otra opción es utilizar el `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` el cual mapea los valores a un modelo. En tu caso necesitarías crear dos clases.

Una de ellas que contenga la información del empleado y otra que tenga el listado de los empleados y el título.

```csharp
class Respuesta
{
    public List<Empleado> Empleados {get; set;}
    public string Titulo {get; set;}
}

class Empleado
{
    public string Nombre {get; set;}
    public string apellidos {get; set;}
}
```

> Nota: los nombre que utilicé para las dos clases solo son representativas para poder darle un nombre.

Con estas dos clases puedes deserializar el json a un modelo, por ejemplo:

```csharp
var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Respuesta>(response.Content);

foreach (var item in jsonObj.Empleados)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Nombre);
}

Console.WriteLine(jsonObj.Titulo);
```

> [Indizadores](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/): Los indizadores permiten indizar las instancias de una clase o struct como matrices. El valor indizado se puede establecer o recuperar sin especificar explícitamente un miembro de tipo o de instancia. Son similares a propiedades, excepto en que sus descriptores de acceso usan parámetros.
>
> [GetValue](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_GetValue.htm): Obtiene el JToken con el nombre de propiedad especificado.
>
> [DeserializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm): Deserializa una cadena (json) al tipo .NET especificado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo, me es útil, marcaré tu respuesta como la correcta aunque haya respondido mi propia pregunta con otra respuesta que también solucionó mi problema. Saludos

Comment: @valle50 vi la respuesta que colocaste y también es súper valida y lo mejor de todo que con el dynamic no necesitas crear los modelos. Excelente.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución utilizando `dynamic`, que hace exactamente lo mismo que en el ejemplo de `PHP` que adjunté, con la ventaja de que ya no es necesario crear `clases` con los atributos que se leerán.

```
        //obtengo el json y lo almaceno en un dynamic para ya no usar clases
        dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);

        //recorro el objeto empleados tal y como el json lo tiene junto con sus atributos
        foreach (var i in jsonObj.empleados)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.nombre);
        }

        //imprimo el valor de la propiedad titulo
        Console.WriteLine(jsonObj.titulo);
```

Comment: Genial que hayas encontrado una forma de hacerlo sin crear modelos y de forma sencilla.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas facil es que uses una libreria para deserealizar el json, podes usar Newtonsoft.Json descargandola desde Nuget. Es la que mas descargas tiene a nivel mundial.

Si viera tu json seria mas facil no errarle, pero primero cuando recibis la respuesta la pasas a texto de esta forma.
Si en la firma de tu metodo no esta la palabra `async` en la linea del `await` te marcara error.

```
var json =await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();//recibe el JSON
```

Luego ese texto lo Deserealizas al tipo de tu objeto, segun entiendo recibis una lista de tu clase `Datos`

```
var resultado = JsonConvert.Deserealize<List<Datos>>(json);


foreach (var persona in Datos)
{
    Console.WriteLine(persona.Nombre); //Lo recorro y se imprimen solo los objetos nombre
}
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que lo que tengo en `c#` sí funciona, pero solo indicándole qué objeto quiero leer, en este caso `empleados` y puedo imprimir todos los nombres, pero no sé cómo imprimir el contenido del objeto `titulo`. Así como en el ejemplo de `PHP`

Comment: Titulo no seria un objeto sino una propiedad, porque no lo imprimis de la misma forma que nombre?